# How to configure storm.yaml when zookeeper cluster use different port?

Tags: cluster-computing, apache-storm, apache-zookeeper

I have configured a zookeeper cluster with 3 servers and it works well. However, the 3 servers use different port. For example, 'zk0' uses 2181 port, 'zk1' uses 2182 port and 'zk2' uses 2183 port.

Then I want to deploy a storm cluster, I don't know how to configure the storm.yaml of zookeeper. I'm willing to configure it like this:

```
storm.zookeeper.servers:
     - "zk0"
     - "zk1"
     - "zk2"
storm.zookeeper.port:
     - 2181
     - 2182
     - 2183
```

But it seems doesn't work.

Anyone can help? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

storm.zookeeper.servers is a list.

storm.zookeeper.port is just a single number.

There's currently no way to run different zookeepers on different ports with storm.

File a feature issue on the apache storm jira if you feel like it.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot! Maybe I should change the ports of the servers to the same one.

Comment: That would be the way to do it. :)